# Script running in windows, but not in ubuntu 20

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, attributeerror

I am setting up a script on a server to notify me the status of a water controller. The following is the beginning of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import smtplib, ssl
import os
import sys

login = "login"
password = "password"

from raincloudy.core import RainCloudy
raincloudy = RainCloudy(login, password)
status = raincloudy.controller.faucet.status
```

I first did this in Windows, Python 3.8.3 and the code ran without any issue. Then, I tested it in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Raspberry Pi, Python 3.8.2 but got the error:

```
raincloudy.controllers
[<RainCloudyController: 5*********>]
status=raincloudy.controller.faucet.status
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
AttributeError: 'RainCloudy' object has no attribute 'controller'
```

The Raincloudy package was initially installed with "pip3". It was uninstalled and re-installed with "sudo pip3". I wonder if the error is related to PATH issue. However I ran the script in VIM (with Python extension) and same error. I program mostly in Windows environment and am not familiar with the file structure in Ubuntu. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: What happens if you try to print the attributes of RainCloudy without accessing the controller attribute. Perhaps the way Windows and Ubuntu handles controllers are different or it could be the library not detecting the controller on Unbuntu.

This is based on the error you provided as it indicates that it is unable to find the controller attribute. Lastly, there might be a slim chance that your credentials are incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. dir(raincloudy) in Windows listed 'controller' attribute but not in Ubuntu. This makes sense now. However, I don't understand why installation of the same package yielded different result. I did log in Ubuntu with an admin account. I am going to try this on another system with Ubuntu 16 and see if same issue.